# Cuda: Access Block and Thread Count within Kernel?

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I have been looking through documentation, and I see:

```
threadIdx
blockDim
```

But I don't see a comprehensive listing of all the information I have access to, and I would like to be able to say:

```
int total_threads = blockDim.total_blocks * theadIdx.total_threads
```

So that if I called the kernel with:

```
<<<N,M>>>

// total_threads would be equivalent to:

N * M
```

How do I access this information (and can I?) from within a Cuda kernel?

Comment: `blockDim` and `gridDim` built-in variables are your friends.  These would be covered in any sort of introductory CUDA material (e.g. `blockDIm` is defined [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/even-easier-introduction-cuda/)).  `blockDim` is effectively `M`, and gridDim is effectively `N`.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Awesome--thanks man!

Comment: @RobertCrovella and yeah, was running across it as you replied

Comment: these variables are documented [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#built-in-variables)